# (int)Math.pow() returning incorrect value

Tags: java, math

I am using the following method to return the value of the parameter `x` cubed.

```
public int cubeNumber(int x)
{
    return (int)(Math.pow((double)x, 3.0));
}
```

When `41243` is passed as the parameter, the method incorrectly returns

> 2147483647

rather than

> 70153726375907

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `70153726375907` is too large for an `int`, so the problem is caused by the cast. You would have to return double to work with such large values.

Comment: If you want to handle arbitrary number then consider using [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: @ernest_k I thought that might be the problem so I replaced the return statement with ```return x*x*x;``` and it worked. It was still returning that large value as an int, yet it worked. Also, why would that cause it to return the wrong number, rather than causing a compile time error?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I get `-269436957` using `return x*x*x;`

Comment: Could be. I'm using an auto grader, as this is for a school assignment. When I use the alternative method, the grader marks it as correct, so I just assumed it worked.

Comment: @a p Always check when you can. Never assume, that way lies bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this.  For large numbers, the return value must be a `long` or perhaps a `BigInteger`.

```
     public static long cubeNumber(long x) {
           return x*x*x;
     }
```

or this

```
     public static long cubeNumber(long x) {
         return (long)Math.pow(x,3);
     }
```

or this

```
     public static BigInteger cubeNumber(long x) {
         return BigInteger.valueOf(x).pow(3);
     }
```

All but the `BigInteger` solution have limitations on precision.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use data type "long", the result is too large for data type "int" to handle. It has reached its data type maximum so will only return the max value of "int"
Check out this link provided (http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-primitive-data-types.php)

Comment: Or even a double.

Comment: For integer values, `double` loses precision well before `long` overflows.